# How do you find the location of an item in a list without using the "index" function?

Tags: python, for-loop, random, indexing, max

I'm a beginner at programming, and I'm trying to create a program that finds the largest number in a list of 1000 random numbers without using the "max" function, and then find the largest numbers position in the list, without using the "index" function (I set the numbers from 0-10 so that I can make sure that the program is working properly). My program so far works, kind of. Sometimes, it will display the location,and when it does, it will display the wrong location, and other times, it will display an error that says that the index is out of range. Could someone please help?

```
import random
num_list = []
for num in range(10):
    num_list.append(random.randrange(0,11))
max_num = -1
for num in num_list:
    if num > max_num:
        max_num = num
        location=num_list[max_num]
print "The computer entered: " + str(num_list) 
print "The largest number in this list is: " + str(max_num) + " The location is: " + str(location)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `num_list[max_num]` is accessing as index the max value.. so for instance in `[1 10 2]`, you are asking for the 10th value in the list! Try to change as:

```
import random
num_list = []
n = 1000
for num in range(n):
    num_list.append(random.randrange(0,n))
max_num = -1
i = 0
for num in num_list:
    if num > max_num:
        max_num = num
        location=i
    i += 1
print "The computer entered: " + str(num_list) 
print "The largest number in this list is: " + str(max_num) + " The location is: " +  str(location)
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited to reflect feedback from @JonClements

```
max_num = -1
for (i, num) in enumerate(num_list):
  if num > max_num:
    location = i
    max_num = num
```

Comment: You're better off using `enumerate` here instead of `range(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate`:

```
import random
num_list = []
for num in range(10):
    num_list.append(random.randrange(0,11))
max_num = -1
location = -1
for index, num in enumerate(num_list): # <-- Use enumerate
    if num > max_num:
        max_num = num
        location=index # <-- Store the index for the largest number we found until now

print "The computer entered: " + str(num_list) 
print "The largest number in this list is: " + str(max_num) + " The location is: " + str(location)
```